# How to convert this cUrl command to java containing form and binary data

Tags: java, curl

I was using an API in which I want to use it in my java project they give an example in curl when I test it, it worked fine with no problem and return the result.
The question is how can I convert this code to java 
this the command I have in cUrl.

```
curl --form text='apple' --form user_audio_file=@D:/apple.wav "https://api.speechace.co/api/scoring/text/v0.1/json?key=mykey&dialect=en-us" | python -m json.tool
```

my java code which i try to use.

```
String Url = "https://api.speechace.co/api/scoring/text/v0.1/json";
String key = "my  key";
String dialect = "en-us";
String user_id = "81ozow";
Url += "?" + "key=" + key + "&dialect=" + dialect + "&user_id=" + user_id;

File file = new File("D:/apple.wav");
byte[] postData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
dis.readFully(postData);
dis.close();

String request = Url;
URL url = new URL(request);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
//conn.addRequestProperty("text", "'apple'");
//conn.addRequestProperty("user_audio_file", "D:/apple.wav");
try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
    wr.write("text='apple'".getBytes());
    wr.flush();
    wr.write("user_audio_file=".getBytes());
    wr.write(postData);
    wr.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    out.println(conn.getErrorStream().toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
out.println("Done upload data");
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
String result = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result += line;
}
rd.close();
out.println(result);
```

but when I use this code I got error from the server as a result, so how can I convert this cUrl code to java, I used many APIs before which give cUrl command as an example and this first time I face such kind of problem I never worked before with command like `--form` and the `| python -m json` how can i write them in java.
I have seen many curls command and I was able to convert it, so any help how can I do that.

Comment: *but when I use this code I got error from the server as a result* What is the error message?

Comment: Do not add the Parameter to the URL. That must be part of the request body

Comment: The documentation of curl should mention all the command line arguments and explain them. Same counts for the `python` command. If you type `man curl`, perhaps some help text shows up.

Comment: without the | python part the command line work in curl so how can i represent the --form part in my java code please any help in this part how can i add it in java and --form with a binary data like the wav sound i should upload

Comment: Error message i got 
{"status":"error","short_message":"error_internal","detail_message":"An internal server error occurred."}

Comment: @Jens thank you bro i checked the duplicated question and you are right and the code worked Thank you for helping me again :)